# Check my integration

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to take the double integral of $4xy$ over a Region $R$ that is bounded by the $x$-axis, $y = x^2$, and the lines $y = 9$ and $x = 5$. My answer was $1,539$ , and I integrated in respect to $x$ first, then $y$.

My bounds when integrating in respect to $x$ was $y^{\frac{1}{2}}$ for my lower bound, and $5$ for my upper bound. My bounds when integrating in respect to $y$ were $0$ for the lower bound, and $9$ for the upper bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I got the same answer by integrating using a $dydx$ order. The integration performed is then
$$\int_0^3\int_0^{x^2} 4xy dydx +\int_3^5\int_0^9 4xy dydx=1539$$